# How to proof inverse function of unions are equal to union of inverse functions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to proof this equation below.
$$
    f^{-1}(\bigcup B_{j})=\bigcup(f^{-1}B_{j})
    $$
I know it's true but I don't have idea how to proof and explain.
Please help.

Comment: I was thinking about this for two days. I tried to make it as logical sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essential is: $$x\in f^{-1}(A)\iff f(x)\in A$$

So the following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in f^{-1}(\bigcup_{j\in J}B_j)$
- $f(x)\in\bigcup_{j\in J}B_j$
- $f(x)\in B_{j_0}$ for some $j_0\in J$
- $x\in f^{-1}(B_{j_0})$ for some $j_0\in J$
- $x\in\bigcup_{j\in J}f^{-1}(B_j)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in f^{-1}(\bigcup B_j)$. This means that there exists $y \in \bigcup B_j$ such that $f(x)=y$. For some $i$ in the index set of $\bigcup$, $y \in B_i \subset \bigcup B_j$. This gives that $ x \in f^{-1}(B_j)$, so we also get $x \in \bigcup f^{-1}(B_j)$.

Conversely, assume $x \in \bigcup f^{-1}(B_j)$. There must exist an $i$ such that $x \in f^{-1} (B_i)$. Again we have $B_i \subset \bigcup B_j$, so $x \in f^{-1}(\bigcup B_j)$.

Therefore $\bigcup f^{-1}(B_j) = f^{-1}(\bigcup B_j)$.